# Idiomatic if-else chain with rx/rxjs

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a piece of flow that in an imperative language could look like:

```
if (something1()) {
  try {
    return loadDataFrom1();
  } catch (err) { }
}

if (something2()) {
  try {
    return loadDataFrom2();
  } catch (err) { }
}

if (something3()) {
  try {
    return loadDataFrom3();
  } catch (err) { }
}

return someSafeDefault();
```

The conditions are not mutually exclusive. It may happen that both `something1()` and `something2()` are true, in which case `loadDataFrom2()` should occur when `loadDataFrom1()` fails.

Now I need to implement this using rxjs 5, with the conditions as well as the operations dealing with Observables.

I can easily achieve the callback hell equivalent by creating Observables and subscribing all over the place, but it's bad for many obvious reasons.

What is a good, idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: are the conditions mutually exclusive (i.e. is it if...else if....else if?)

Comment: @Meir See update.

Comment: What are `somethingX()` and `loadDataFromX()`? If these don't return Observables then you can use just `map()` or `concatMap()` depending on what you want to do.

Comment: The conditions as well as the operations are dealing with (async) observables.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to promises and using async/await comes to mind as a possible solution, but using pure rxjs you can do something like this:

```js
var something1: () => Observable<boolean>;
var something2: () => Observable<boolean>;
var something3: () => Observable<boolean>;

type MyData = { data: string };
var loadDataFrom1: () => Observable<MyData>;
var loadDataFrom2: () => Observable<MyData>;

var first = something1()
    .take(1)
    .filter(something => something ==  true)
    .flatMap(() => loadDataFrom1())
    .catch(e => Observable.of({ message: e }))
    // Take one result, this will be either the sucessful result from lodaData or the err or object { message: e }
    .take(1);

var second = something2()
    .take(1)
    .filter(something => something ==  true)
    .flatMap(() => loadDataFrom2())
    .catch(e => Observable.of({ message: e }))
    // Take one result, this will be either the sucessful result from lodaData or the err or object { message: e }
    .take(1);

var third = something3()
    .take(1)
    .filter(something => something ==  true)
    .flatMap(() => loadDataFrom2())
    .catch(e => Observable.of({ message: e }))
    // Take one result, this will be either the sucessful result from lodaData or the err or object { message: e }
    .take(1);

var safeDefault = Observable.of({data: 'My safe result'});

var result = Observable
    .concat(first, second, third, safeDefault)
    // filter away all exception results
    .filter(data => data.message == null)
    // take only one actuall valid result  
    .take(1);
```